# Cannot view Gitlab CI Pipeline Test results on Cypress Dashboard

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to run my 1st CI test in Gitlab. The pipeline works perfectly but the problem is I can't see the results on the cypress dash board. [Watch this video here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oa9t82hip11d9b5/Can%27t%20Run%20Gitab%20pipeline%20with%20Cypress%20Dashboard.mp4?dl=0) .

How do I fix this?

Steps:

1. Open cypress dashboard and add CI
2. Copy dashboard information and this information to the cypress.json and package.json files in gitlab
3. Run your test in gitlab pipeline.

Expected result

view test results in cypress dashboard

Actual results

I cannot see my Gitlab pipeline test results

Comment: Don't you need to create a new record key in Project settings => Record Keys first? Isn't that one only an example?

Comment: I added the new key to the project in the git lab and I successfully comitted them